# Problem of cofinal functions and same cofinality

Tags: set-theory

I'm trying to prove something and I think I almost got it, but I would like to know if my reasoning is okay because I'm not quite sure.

"If $\gamma$ is a limit ordinal and $f$ is a cofinal function from $\alpha$ to  $\gamma$ that is not decreasing then: cf($\gamma$)=cf($\alpha$)." I now the result is true if $f$ is strictly increasing. I also now that $\alpha$ must be a limit ordinal. So I proposed the following function from $\alpha$ to  $\gamma$ defined recursively:

$g(0)=f(0)$

g($\beta$)=min{f($\lambda$) such that f($\lambda$)>g($\delta$), $\delta$ $\in$ $\beta$}

I have proved that this function is strictly increasing and that it must be cofinal from $\alpha$ to  $\gamma$. But I'm not quite sure the function is well defined. If is not well defined then let $\beta$ $\in$ $\alpha$ be the smaller element such that $g$ is not well defined, that would mean that $f$ is constant from that point on ¿right?, but that can't be because it is cofinal with an limit ordinal. ¿Is these reasoning okay? 
Thank you

Comment: You need more than "infinite ordinal" : $\omega +1$ is an infinite ordinal with cofinality $1$. It is by the way a counterexample to your "theorem" : if $f:\omega \to \omega +1$ is defined by $f(n) = \omega$ then obviously $f$ isn't decreasing and it's cofinal, but the cofinalities aren't the same. What you can get, though, is an inequality between cofinalities

Comment: You are right, I meant to say limit ordinal. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

No it's not the case that the function is well defined. Consider the following example: Let $\delta$ be a regular cardinal, and let $\delta+\delta$ be the ordinal addition. Take a function from $f:\delta+\delta\to\delta+\delta$ such that $f(\alpha)=\delta$ for $\alpha\leq\delta$ and $f(\alpha)=\alpha$ for $\alpha\geq\delta+1$. This is of course non-decreasing and cofinal. Now the function $g$ that you define is defined for $\alpha\in\delta$ as $g(\alpha)=\delta+\alpha$. It's not hard to see that you cannot define $g(\delta)$. Indeed $\{f(\gamma)\mid f(\gamma)>g(\beta)\text{ for all }\beta\in\delta\}$ is empty.

To guarantee that this doesn't happen, the domain of your function $g$ needs to be $cf(\alpha)$, rather than $\alpha$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know of a better way I could prove this?  I think I could define $g$ from cf($\alpha$) to $\gamma$  and use the fact that cf(cf($\alpha$))=cf($\alpha$). Is there a better way?

Comment: @chinos007: Yes. Define a function the exact same way, only with domain $cf(\alpha)$. Then think what was the gap in your proof: You said that if the set is empty then it means the function is constant, but there was another possibility, that you have covered the whole domain of the function. Then explain why the fact that $cf(cf(\alpha))=cf(\alpha)$ is enough to guarantee that this second possibility cannot be the case. I can't think of something simpler right now.